# OLS on standard deviation vs OLS on variance

Tags: variance, inference, standard-deviation

As a part of my masters thesis, I am trying to create predictors of volatility such that they minimise the mean squared forecasting errors. To do this I compute standard deviations of all my assets in the historical sample $\sigma_H$ and for my estimation period $\sigma_E$. $\sigma$ is a 1-by-N vector containing the standard deviations. My initial "guess" is that past standard deviation is a good predictor for future volatility.

Then I estimate the regression

$\sigma_E = \alpha + \beta \sigma_H + \epsilon$  $(1)$

I do this for a learning period, then do the mean of all the coefficients I have estimated.
Then I can predict future volatility out-of-sample by the linear combination:

$\sigma_{future} = \bar{\alpha} + \bar{\beta} \sigma_H $   $(2)$

Now, my professor does this in his original paper by estimating the same process using variance $\sigma^2$ instead of standard deviation $\sigma$. That is, estimating the regression, doing the linear combination, and then using square root on the estimate for future variance to find the estimate for future standard deviation;

$\sigma_{future}^{2} = \bar{\alpha} + \bar{\beta} \sigma_H^{2} $ $(3)$

$\sigma_{future} = \sqrt{\sigma_{future}^{2}}$ $(4)$

I would think the relationship between the $\sigma$ and $\sigma^2$ is lost after the linear combination in $(3)$.

Any input on this would be highly appreciated : )

Comment: hi :-) imho, computing sigma^2, im just guessing it had historical purpose (much more simple to calculate ^2 then sigma) and maybe stability issues ("outlayers" get higher "penalty" in ^2) ... aha, you did calculate sigma, but you applying sigma^2 at step 3..  is it because prof. calculate sigma^2? I think both approaches as fitting sigma, as sigma^2 seems good .. imho, when doing fit for sigma use sigma .. (im guessing formula 2) .. like electric voltage sigma^2..you fit sigma, but you put sigma^2 which can give too many power, or too low power..if you want to put s^2, do fitting on sigma^2

Comment: (mixing approach can give suboptimal solution (all credit to @author) and lower "attributes" model was trained for .. in your project(master thesis) you can do 1.fit sigma / use sigma 2. fit sigma^2 use sigma^2 and compare performance ... but at 99.999% im sure mixing give suboptimal .. you can mention it to prof. maybe he will be curious about your results in his field